# Use rmarkdown/knitr to hold all code until the end

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, reproducible-research

I'd like to be able to generate a document using knitr/rmarkdown that keeps all the output together, but leaves the code until the end, ideally as a referenced footnote of sorts (i.e. the code for each figure or output can be looked up in the appendix using a footnote). Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you mean.
You can add a label to your original code chunk and then refer to it using a `ref.label` property and prevent its further execution with `eval=FALSE`.

For instance:

`````
 # Header
 Bla bla ...
 ````{r plot1,echo=FALSE}
 x = rnorm(100,10,5)
 y = rnorm(100,10,5)
 plot(x,y)
 ````

 # Appendix

 Code chunk:
 ````{r ref.label="plot1",eval=FALSE}
 ```
`````

The first chunk is executed (without echo) and shows a figure, the second chunk just echoes the first chunk's source.

Answer (score 6):

One solution is add this chunk at the end.

```
{r ref.label=knitr::all_labels(), echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
```

Then you will have all the code together whitout evaluation.